# How can I login to a VBulletin PHP website with C#?

Tags: c#, http, browser, request, vbulletin

How can I login to a VBulletin PHP website with C#?

I have a VBulletin php based community code board.

I would like to login to the board via a C# program that I will build.

My problem is that even though I have proved all the necessary variables in the data query such as `vb_login_username="USERNAME"&vb_login_md5password="MD5 # OF PASSWORD"`, when I attempt to login, the website just responds with the HTML of the main page as if I had not tried to login at all.

What is the other data that I must set for the website to recognise my program as a browser and how can I correctly make a query to a VBulletin board to login?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that somebody from [another website](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/53896-c-vbulletin-login-function/) has made which seems to work and answer your question.

> Well, in one of my programs it was necessary to login to vBulletin
>   (and stay logged in) so I wrote a function which does that.
>
> Requires: System.Net; & System.IO;
>
> ```
>     static string login(string url, string username, string password)
>     {
>         HttpWebRequest req  = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
>         string cookie       = "";
>         string values       = "vb_login_username="+username+"&vb_login_password="+password
>                             + "securitytoken=guest&"
>                             + "cookieuser=checked&"
>                             + "do=login";
>         req.Method          = "POST";
>         req.ContentType     = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
>         req.ContentLength   = values.Length;
>         CookieContainer a   = new CookieContainer();
>         req.CookieContainer = a;
>
>         System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; // prevents 417 error
>
>         using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)) 
>       {
>           writer.Write(values);           }
>
>         HttpWebResponse c = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
>         foreach (Cookie cook in c.Cookies)            {
>           cookie = cookie + cook.ToString() + ";";            }
>
>         return cookie;
>     }
> ```
>
> It returns the cookie data so when loading other pages of the site,
>   you can just send the cookies and stay logged in with the
>   headers.add("cookie", cookie) method. And an example;
>
> ```
> string cookie = login("forum.codecall.net/login.php?do=login", "username", "password"); // include http and www (I don't have 10
> ```
>
> forum posts)
>        Console.Write(cookie);
>        Console.Read();
>
> This has only been tested on vBulletin 3.x versions.

I think what your problem may have been is that you were not encoding your strings to match the encoding that VBulleting uses and/or that you may have been not correctly sending the request.

Comment: [code] string cookie = login("http://fxp.co.il/login.php?do=login", "username", "password");
            richTextBox1.Text = cookie;[/code]

Comment: And my richbox showed empty content after running this.Does it not work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Function login(ByVal url As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As String

        Dim req As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim cookie As String = String.Empty
        Dim values As String = "vb_login_username=" + username + "&vb_login_password=" + password _
                            + "securitytoken=guest&" _
                            + "cookieuser=checked&" _
                            + "do=login"
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        req.ContentLength = values.Length
        Dim a As Net.CookieContainer = New Net.CookieContainer()
        req.CookieContainer = a

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False ' prevents 417 error

        Using writer As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
            writer.Write(values)
        End Using

        Dim c As Net.HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
        For Each cook In c.Cookies
            cookie = cookie + cook.ToString() + ";"
        Next

        Return cookie
    End Function
```

Comment: add some comments to your answer

Comment: VB.NET version (tested).